# Brachistochrone Problem for Spacecraft

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, variational-principle, brachistochrone-problem

I understand how the [Brachistochrone Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) works, and do understand how the friction is added to it, however I am unsure of how to use the Brachistochrone Problem for use in spacecraft.

We know that one solution to the Brachistochrone Problem is the following:

$$x=a(\theta - \sin\theta)$$

$$y=a(1 - \cos\theta).$$

Now, to further explore that idea, I'd like to ask how one could add the thrust force of a spacecraft into the equation for the optimal path taken  for it to go into its orbit.

Comment: Do you have a good formalism in mind for what this thrust might look like? Can it go in any direction or just, say, forward, or just, say upwards.  Either way this'll be an interesting question, though, the answer will be cool to know

Comment: Hey, yes I was thinking of the thrust going basically just upward, which should make it a little easier